# Is 12.10 incompatible with a 2011 Lenovo computer?

Tags: 12.10, lenovo, compatibility

I apologize that I can't say the specific model of the laptop; it is currently being repaired and I have not written it down.

The installation of 12.10 went off without a hitch, but after turning it off for the first time I found that my device froze at the BIOS screen and failed to respond to any input methods. I looked up this problem and found that in most cases it has to do with problematic hardware, so I took the laptop into a local repair shop and the clerk opened up the case and said that there was nothing wrong inside; that the problem was that the operating system is incompatible with the device. This strikes me as unlikely, as the device is less than two years old and was one of the higher-end models.

My question is this: is  Ubuntu 12.10 really incompatible with my recent device, or is the clerk just swindling me by charging for the extra service or re-installing Windows 7?

Comment: Seriously doubt installing Ubuntu had anything to do with crashing your computer's BIOS and failing to respond to any inputs.

Comment: If you can't get into the bios, you have some bad hardware.  If the clerk couldn't get that far, then he had no rational basis for claiming there was nothing wrong, so he's a quack; ask for your money back.

Comment: Ubuntu works perfectly on my Lenovo T60 and my Lenovo T410i. I would have no hesitancy to install it again.